# WSO2 API Manager Public NAT IP

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed the api manager on a windows server 2008. The server has a LAN-IP and a Public-IP over NAT.

Example:
LAN-IP: 192.168.100.1
Public-IP over NAT: 10.0.0.10

I want to test the API Manager over the Public-IP, but the Server works only local with the LAN-IP. Has someone an idea, how can I get the api manager to work over the Public-IP? The Ports are open on the firewall.
THX

Comment: Can you add <HostName>EXTERNAL-IP</HostName> to API_MANAGER/repository/conf/carbon.xml and check(replace EXTERNAL-IP with your public IP )?

Comment: Hallo thanks for replay. I have added the External IP to <HostName>.But the link
https:/EXTERNEL-IP:9443/carbon doesn’t work

Comment: Hi, since you want to change the management console url hostname,Adding to above <HostName> entry ,can you check with changing <MgtHostName> config to your public IP in  API_MANAGER/repository/conf/carbon.xml

Answer (score 0):

Please try out with the following configurations. Note to restart the server once done.

1. Set the HostName and MgtHostName in <%APIM_HOME%>/repository/conf/carbon.xml to the public IP address.
2. Set the bind-address parameter of the http and https s found in the <%APIM_HOME%>/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file to the public IP.
3. Set the  as below in the <%APIM_HOME$>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml file.

http://<-- Public-IP -- >:${http.nio.port},https://<-- Public-IP -- >:${https.nio.port}

Thanks,
Nuwan.

Comment: Hey, not able to understand point 3. I think you've missed something.