# WSO2 API manager not accessible from public IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have deployed WSO2 API manager V 1.10.0 on AWS EC2  - Windows server 2012. I have also associated an elastic IP to the server. I have done changes mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141094/wso2-api-manager-public-nat-ip?answertab=active#tab-top) make it run on the public IP but the server is not reachable. To make sure the security group is set properly, I have also have a IIS configured(port 80) and is accesible from my local. I have allowed all TCP ports from anywhere.

Comment: What is the URL you're trying to access? Are you sure server is up and running? what is the output of `netstat -pln | grep 9443`?

Comment: I have started the server and below is the URL I get and I am trying to access.                                                                                          Publisher Default
 Context : http://35.154.40.254:9763/publisher
[2016-11-24 06:10:56,207]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Store Default Con
text : http://35.154.40.254:9763/store

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -an 1 | find "9443" 
   TCP    172.31.28.227:49335    172.31.28.227:9443     SYN_SENT
   TCP    172.31.28.227:49375    172.31.28.227:9443     SYN_SENT
  TCP    172.31.28.227:49376    172.31.28.227:9443     SYN_SENT
  TCP    172.31.28.227:49381    35.154.40.254:9443     SYN_SENT
  TCP    172.31.28.227:49382    35.154.40.254:9443     SYN_SENT
  TCP    172.31.28.227:49383    35.154.40.254:9443     SYN_SENT
  TCP    172.31.28.227:49381    35.154.40.254:9443     SYN_SENT

Comment: Is `35.154.40.254` the public IP? can you ping it from your local machine?

Comment: This is EC2 and ping may not work as I have not allowed ICMP but when I browse http://35.154.40.254 I get to see the IIS default page. That means server is listening on port 80. I have allowed all TCP ports.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like port 9443 or 9763 is open.

```
bhathiya@bhathiya-x1:~/git/msf4j$ nmap 35.154.40.254 -sT -v

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-11-24 17:48 +0530
Initiating Ping Scan at 17:48
Scanning 35.154.40.254 [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 17:48, 0.18s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 17:48
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 17:48, 0.06s elapsed
Initiating Connect Scan at 17:48
Scanning ec2-35-154-40-254.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com (35.154.40.254) [1000 ports]
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 35.154.40.254
Discovered open port 135/tcp on 35.154.40.254
Discovered open port 3389/tcp on 35.154.40.254
Discovered open port 445/tcp on 35.154.40.254
Discovered open port 139/tcp on 35.154.40.254
Discovered open port 49159/tcp on 35.154.40.254
Discovered open port 49155/tcp on 35.154.40.254
Discovered open port 49154/tcp on 35.154.40.254
Completed Connect Scan at 17:49, 29.76s elapsed (1000 total ports)
Nmap scan report for ec2-35-154-40-254.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com (35.154.40.254)
Host is up (0.27s latency).
Not shown: 992 filtered ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
80/tcp    open  http
135/tcp   open  msrpc
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
3389/tcp  open  ms-wbt-server
49154/tcp open  unknown
49155/tcp open  unknown
49159/tcp open  unknown

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 30.03 seconds
```

Comment: I opened the both the ports from the windows firewall and it worked